# How to use AWS SDK in Drupal to get up-to-date information

Tags: drupal, sdk, amazon-web-services

I am building a Drupal website to monitor and control our AWS EC2 instances.

Using the AWS SDK, I'm able to create blocks to display the data.

However, I'm looking for a way to expose the data to Drupal in such a way that it can be used to create views or blocks, like any other Drupal node.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/ and get  the ouput in json.

Then use views to import this json and format it as per your needs.

cheers,
Vishal

Comment: Ah, that seems to be the method I'm looking for; I'll now look into how to import that in JSON. Wild guess: normally I should write a module to use the SDK to get the data, and create the views from my module?

Comment: I think we  are in luck. check  out http://drupal.org/project/feeds this might be the right one  for you.

Comment: Is feeds not used only for one-off imports or creation of new content each time? The information I need must be live, meaning that if you refresh the page you get new info; I'm writing an interface for my EC2 Instances in fact...

Comment: sorry I thought from reading the project details you can do a live import. Anyways back to the topic create a custom fields and save the json data in your module. custom fields are available to views to access and there you can do you thing. This should work for d7 I am not sure for d6

Comment: Ah ok; i'm using d7, so no problem there. Thanks for the help!! I'll try it and let you know how it goes